# Fetching json response from gists API returning code 200 not JSON in the response body

Tags: android, json, github, kotlin, retrofit

I am trying to fetch `JSON` from gists of GitHub using coding in Kotlin. I am receiving a response as

```
E/tag: Response{protocol=http/1.1, code=200, message=OK, url=https://api.github.com/gists/02d3e6e910739c35fc7d14b3fd16466a}
```

I want to fetch `json` in the response.

This is how I called the URL an dis code for my `MainActivity`

```
private val retrofit= Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl("https://api.github.com/")
    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
    .build()

private val postsApi = retrofit.create(RequestApi::class.java)
private val response= postsApi.getAllData()

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    response.enqueue(object: Callback<NewResponse>{
        override fun onFailure(call: Call<NewResponse>, t: Throwable) {
           //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
        }

        override fun onResponse(call: Call<NewResponse>, response: Response<NewResponse>) {
            //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
            val mResponse= response.raw().toString()
            Log.e("tag", mResponse)
        }
    })
}
```

My Request code

```
interface RequestApi {

@GET("gists/02d3e6e910739c35fc7d14b3fd16466a")
fun getAllData(): Call<NewResponse>
}
```

My CVResponse Class is

```
class CVResponse {

@SerializedName("data")
val data: Data? = null
}
```

I want to fetch json like below

```
{
   "data":{
      "name":"Maria",
      "summary":"Likable and dedicated IT consultant with over 5 years of experience in a fast-paced fin-tech company. Eager to offer superb analytical and computer skills to help ABC Inc grow its client base. In previous roles recognized for top company-wide quality satisfaction rating.",
      "skills":[
         {
            "type":"Design Languages",
            "languages":[
               "HTML",
               "XML",
               "CSS"
            ]
         },
         {
            "type":"Language",
            "languages":[
               "Java",
               "C#",
               "C++",
               "Kotlin"
            ]
         },
         {
            "type":"Scripting Language",
            "languages":[
               "Javascript"
            ]
         },
         {
            "type":"Server Language",
            "languages":[
               "Php"
            ]
         },
         {
            "type":"Operating System",
            "languages":[
               "Windows",
               "Mac",
               "Android"
            ]
         },
         {
            "type":"Database",
            "languages":[
               "Sqlite",
               "SQL",
               "MySQL"
            ]
         },
         {
            "type":"Frameworks",
            "languages":[
               "Netbeans",
               "Eclipse",
               "ADT-Bundle"
            ]
         }
      ],
      "education_bg":[
         {
            "position":"Post-Graduate in IBM",
            "Major":"International Business",
            "from":"2018",
            "to":"2019",
            "institute_name":"Douglas College"
         },
         {
            "position":"Post-Graduate in ICT",
            "Major":"Information Technology",
            "from":"2017",
            "to":"2018",
            "institute_name":"Douglas College"
         },
         {
            "position":"Bachelors in CSE",
            "Major":"Computer Science",
            "from":"2010",
            "to":"2014",
            "institute_name":"Douglas College"
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Call `response.body()` to retrieve NewResponse object. Consider add error handling for other HTTP status codes on `onResponse()` method. Remind that the returned value of 'response.body()' might be null, so it's a good idea handle this scenario too.